# Exceptions - what is "exceptional"?

Tags: php, laravel, exception

I've read that exceptions shouldn't be used for directing the flow of your application but should be used to recover the application to a stable state when something "exceptional" happens, for example, when you fail to connect to a database.

An example of where an exception shouldn't be used would be a user providing an incorrect login. It wouldn't be an exception since it's expected that that will happen.

I'm not sure whether the following case is exceptional or not:

I'm currently designing a simple blog. A "post" is assigned to just one "category". In my posts table I have a category_id field with a foreign key constraint.

Now, I'm using Laravel so if I try to delete a category that currently has posts in it, I believe it should throw an \Illuminate\Database\QueryException because of the foreign key constraint. Therefore should I rely on this and write code like:

```
try {
    $category->delete();
}
catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
    // Tell the user that they can't delete the category because there are posts assigned to it
}
```

or since I know how I want my blog to work, should I use:

```
if ($category->posts->isEmpty()) {
    $category->delete();
}
else {
    // Tell the user they can't delete...
}
```

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think this is primarily opinion-based, but I would go with the second option. Why? 1. So that the rule is clear. 2. So that other kinds of database exceptions don't give a misleading error. 3. So that if someone turns on cascading deletes, your logic still operates the same.

Comment: continuing @DarkFalcon's answer, throwing exceptions is a heavier operation, so you should only use it in case you really don't except something to happen.

Answer (score 1):

It is very opinion based, so i'll give you my opinion: 
Exceptions are powerfull, because you can attach a lot of information with it - and you can send them "up the callstack" without having hundrets of methods checking the return value of any call and returning whatever to their own caller.

This allows you to easily handle an error at the desired layer in the callstack.

A Method should return, what is *the result* of the call (even if it's void). If the call fails for any reason, there should be *no* return value.

Errors should not be transported by returnvalues, but with exceptions.

Imagine a function doing db-queries: `KeyAlreadyExistsException`, `InvalidSyntaxException` and `NullPointerException` - most likely you want to handle this "errors" at very different parts in your code.

(One is a code-error, one is a query-error, one is a logical-error)

Example one, easy "handling":

```
try{
  method1(1);
}catch (Exception $e){
  //Handle all but NullpointerExceptions here.
}
---
method1($s){
  try{
    method2($s+2);
  } catch (NullPointerException $e){
    //only deal with NPEs here, others bubble up the call stack.
  }
} 
---
method2($s){
  //Some Exception here.
}
```

Example two - you see the required "nesting", and the stack-depth is only 2 here.

```
 $result = method1(1);
 if ($result === 1){
   //all good
 }else{
  //Handle all but NullpointerExceptions here.
 }
 ---
 method1($s){
   $result = method2($s+2);
   if ($result === 1){
     return $result;
   }else{
     if ($result === "NullPointerException"){
       //do something
     }  
 } 

method2($s){
  //Exception here.
}
```

Especially for maintainance, Exceptions have huge advantages: If you add a new "Exception" - the worstcase will be an unhandled exception, but code execution will break.

If you add new "return errors", you need to make sure, that every Caller is aware of these new errors:

```
function getUsername($id){
   // -1 = id not found
   $name = doQuery(...);
   if (id not found) return -1;
   else return $name;
}
```

vs

```
function getUsername($id){
   $name = doQuery(...);
   if (id not found) throw new IdNotFoundException(...);
   return $name;
}
```

Now consider the handling in both cases:

```
if (getUsername(4)=== -1) { //error } else { //use it }
```

vs

```
try{
  $name = getUsername(4);
  //use it
}catch (IdNotFoundException $e){
   //error
}
```

And now, you add the return code `-2`: First way would assume the username to be `-2`, until the error code is implemented. Second way (Another Exception) would cause the execution to stop with an unhandled exception somewhere way up in the callstack.

Dealing with return values (of any kind) for error-transportation is error prone and errors might vanish somewhere, turning into a "wrong" interpreted result.

Using exceptions is safer: You either have a return value to use, or a (handled or unhandled) exception, but no "wrong values" due to autocasts etc.